# Jooq (SQLite) not inserting

Tags: java, sqlite, save, pojo, jooq

im trying to insert a new record in my table

```
public void saveNewBook(ModelBook bookFilled) {

ModelBook book1 = create.newRecord("MyTableOfBooks", bookFilled); //in this part keep saying:
```

**The method newRecord(Table, Object) in the type DSLContext is not applicable for the arguments (String, ModelBook)**

but its the same way as this: http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.5/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos/

so i cant do the:

```
//book1.store();

}
```

Comment: For the record, [this question was also asked on the jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/VwLAq9uFyb0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DSLContext.newRecord(Table, Object)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord-org.jooq.Table-java.lang.Object-) method takes a [`Table`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html) reference as its first argument, not a string. Ideally, you would pass a generated reference of your book table to that method.